# Sum of partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Suppose my table has below 3 columns:

```
Col1  Col2 Col3
2     A    A
3     B    A
4     C    A
4     D    B
5     E    B
6     F    B
```

Output

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
9    A    A
9    B    A
9    C    A
15   D    B
15   E    B
15   F    B
```

I want grouping based on column 3 and want to sum first 3 rows and they should show as 9,9,9 in output. I want to fetch all records from column 2 also.

```
Select Sum(Col1), Col2, Col3 from Table
Group by Col2, Col3
```

I have used `group by` and `over ()`. Not able to get this output.
Kindly let me know how this can be achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `SUM()` as an analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Col1) OVER (PARTITION BY Col3) AS Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Col2;
```

Comment: Love the evolving questions  ...  +1